# Яке головне значення дієслова "займатися"? І чи можна займатися наукою, політикою, здоров'ям, коханням тощо?

Tags: значення-слів, дієслова, омоніми

СУМ подає значення [**`займатися`**](http://sum.in.ua/s/zajmatysja) в такому порядку:

> **Займатися 1**, аюся, аєшся, недок., Зайнятися діал. Займитися, займуся, займешся, док.
>
> 1. чим. **Робити, здійснювати що-небудь**. *Олександр то брався за перо, то знову його відкладав: не хотілося нікому писати і не було
>      бажання будь-чим займатися* (Панас Кочура, Золота грамота, 1960, 328);
>      //  **Вивчати що-небудь, оволодівати чимсь, присвячувати себе
>      якому-небудь заняттю, якійсь справі.** *Був би Вам дуже вдячний за
>      всяку поміч і раду, тим більш цінну, що Ви займаєтесь етнографією*
>      (Михайло Коцюбинський, III, 1956, 226).
> 2. ким, чим. **Приділяти увагу комусь, чомусь, виявляти інтерес до кого-, чого-небудь**. *Дора, а більше ще пан К., взяли собі нині за
>      обов'язок опікуватися гарною дівчиною, хоч нею займались і інші дами*
>      (Ольга Кобилянська, III, 1956, 84); *Антоші зробилось скучно. Він вже
>      чув дядькові сни і вважав кращим зайнятись своїм Нептуном [собакою]*
>      (Михайло Коцюбинський, II, 1955, 387); *Тепер уже можна б зайнятися і
>      самим собою. Розсупонитись від солдатського реміняччя, поголитись,
>      покупатись, поспівати на дозвіллі...* (Олесь Гончар, III, 1959, 446); 
>      //  з ким, рідко. **Навчати кого-небудь, керувати чиїмсь навчанням**.
>      — *Ти з ним, Наталю, займися на дозвіллі: здібний юнак, талановитий*
>      (Степан Васильченко, III, 1960, 346).
> 3. тільки недок. Пас. до займати 1, 2, 5, 6.
>
> **Займатися 2**, аюся, аєшся, недок., Зайнятися діал. Займитися, займуся, займешся, док.
>
> 1. тільки 3 ос. **Починати горіти, спалахувати полум'ям; загорятися.** *Бараболя, витирав сірник. Він спочатку чахкає, шипить, блискає сіркою та смородом і нарешті займається* (Михайло Стельмах, Кров людська..,
>      I, 1957, 60); *Аж глядь, палати зайнялися. Пожар! пожар!* (Тарас
>      Шевченко, II, 1953, 98); ...
> 2. тільки 3 ос. П**очинати світитися, сяяти**. З*оря на небі рожева уже починала займатись* (Леся Українка, I, 1951, 23); *Коли займаються
>      вогні Над рідною столицею, Дніпро ввижається мені Ясною блискавицею*
>      (Микола Нагнибіда, Вибр., 1957, 42); ...;   //  **Наставати,
>      починатися (про ранок, день)**. *Ніжний, прозорий займався над полем
>      липневий ранок* (Василь Козаченко, Гарячі руки, 1960, 146); *По
>      темноті настав світанок, зайнявся день, і схід в огні* (Уляна
>      Кравченко, Вибр., 1958, 94).

Натомість, професор Пономарів наполегливо ([стаття від 2011 року](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/ukrainian/ponomariv/2011/05/post-47.html), [стаття від 2015 року](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2015/05/150512_ponomariv_blog55_ko)) стверджує, що

> Українською мовою первісне значення слова **`займатися`** –
>   загорятися, спалахувати. Наприклад: "Язичок полум’я блиснув – і солома
>   зайнялася". Омонімічне **`займатися`**, що набуло нового значення
>   шляхом метафоризації, доречне тоді, коли йдеться про захоплення,
>   зацікавлення. **`Займатися музикою`**, **`займатися танцями`**,
>   **`спортом`** і под.
>
> У решті випадків потрібно вживати дієслів **`працювати`**,
>   **`навчатися`**, **`робити`**, **`вести`**, **`братися`**, **`поратися`** тощо. Наприклад, щ*о робить (а не чим займається) доброчинний фонд?* *Підприємство веде ще й комерційну діяльність. Над
>   якою темою ви працюєте? Я відвідую бібліотеку. Навчаюся на курсах
>   іноземних мов. Працюю над цим питанням*.

**Тож де правда? Що стосовно цього кажуть інші поважні мовознавці?**

Comment: Я погоджуюсь з професором. Стосовно `займатись коханням` - то `кохатись` (або навіть взагалі - `сексуватись`).

Comment: А корінь цього слова – **яти** – займає чимало місця в етимологічному словнику [1](http://imgur.com/un1Mki0.png) - [2](http://imgur.com/5YvIPY6.png) - [3](http://imgur.com/P5XX0xU.png). Теж підтримую ствердження пана Пономаріва.

Comment: У "Як ми говоримо" теж є про це дієслово: http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/zajmatysya-pracyuvaty-zhyty-z-chohos-trudytysya-chymos

Comment: Пономарів [у деяких випадках](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/927/4) схильний до пуризму. Якщо в СУМ-11 є цитати класиків, що однозначно доводять використання «займатися» у значенні «робити, здійснювати», то, по-моєму, він неправий. Хіба що якщо це значення, навпаки, *вийшло з мови* з часів класиків або якщо він відчуває якісь тонкощі, до яких *варто рухатись* — але не так, що це значення строго недоречне зараз.

Comment: @Sasha, а ще ж є іменник [*заняття*](http://sum.in.ua/s/zanjattja). Зізнаюсь, я й сама, неодноразово чувши думку Пономаріва, Антоненка-Давидовича й інших щодо *займатися*, намагаюсь уникати вживання в обговорюваному значенні. В принципі, це й непогано, адже спонукає до пошуку синонімів, замінників, що зрештою, таки збагачує словниковий запас, сподіваюсь :) . Але іноді дійсно не варто бути аж надто прискіпливими і таврувати *росіянизмом* те, що насправді ним не є.

Answer (score 14):

Словник Бориса Грінченка надає тільки [друге значення](http://services.ulif.org.ua/grinch/Entry/index?wordid=12692&page=334&is_name_filter=false&word_type_selection=0&name_fl=): загорятися, спалахувати. Тобто перше значення швидше за все з'явилося у <strike>радянські часи</strike> (див. нижче). Отже пан Пономарів *можливо* має рацію.

**Додаток від 5 серпня 2017**

Хотів би додати деякі подробиці. Я порахував напів-автоматично, у якому значенні використовували це слово письменники. Для цього я скористувався виразом `.{0,100}зай[мн]\S+с[ья].{0,100}`. Це дало мені змогу побачити контекст і з'ясувати значення.

Я обробив три збірки, але відкинув всі сучасні твори (крім Винничука для порівняння). Збірки трохи перетинаються і цього аналізу недостатньо для наукової праці, але висновок зробити можна. У другому стовпчику кількість появ у значенні «спалахувати», у третьому — у значеннях «робити» та «приділяти увагу». Якщо слово з'являлося кілька разів у реченні, я рахував це за одну появу. Також я намагався не враховувати появи у вступних статтях та коментарях.

Для пошуку у текстових файлах, я скористався рекурсивним `grep`. Для пошуку в epub, я використав таку команду.

```
for f in *.epub; do 
   dirName=${f%.epub}
   mkdir "$dirName"
   unzip -d "$dirName" "$f"
   grep -ioPR '.{0,100}зай[мн]\S+с[ья].{0,100}' "$dirName" >> zvit.txt
done
```

**Збірка 1**

Українські твори, які можна завантажити для PocketBook (epub).

```
Письменник     спалах. робити  нар.
Грінченко         1     0      1863
Кропивницький     1     0      1840
Куліш             1     0      1819
Мирний            4     1      1849
Нечуй-Левицький  12     0      1838
Руданський        1     0      1833
Старицький        4     0      1840
Франко            2     3      1856
Шевченко          1     0      1814
Українка          7     0      1871
```

**Збірка 2**

Твори з моєї книгозбірні у форматі epub.

```
Письменник         спалах.   робити  нар.
Вовчок                4         0    1833
Коцюбинський         12        10    1864
Куліш                 7         1    1819
Самійленко(В)         1        11    1864
Старицький            7         0    1840
Тютюнник(Григорій)    7        11    1920
Українка             12         0    1871
Франко                4         2    1856
```

**Збірка 3**

Твори з моєї книгозбірні у текстових форматах (txt, html, і т.ін.)

```
Письменник    спалах.  робити  нар.
Васильченко      5        0    1878
Винничук         1       16    1952
Квітка-Основ.    1        0    1778
Королева         1        0    1888
Костомаров       1        0    1817
Лепкий(Б)       11        2    1872
Підмогильний    21        1    1901
Сковорода        0        8    1722
Сосюра           2        2    1897
Тесленко         2        1    1882
Хвильовий        4        3    1893
Яновський        6       12    1902
```

**Висновки**

Друге значення (робити або приділяти увагу) з'явилося набагато раніше ніж радянські часи, але чомусь Грінченко це значення у свій словник не додав. Якби не Сковорода, здавалося б, що це слово почали використовувати у другому значенні десь після 1885 року (подивіться роки народження і додайте до них 25-30). Виникають такі питання. По-перше, чи не з'явилось друге значення у Сковороди під впливом московської мови, якою користувалися більшість поміщиків навіть в Україні? По-друге, чи не результат це роботи пізніших упорядників і редакторів?

У будь-якому разі, мені здається, що головне значення — це «спалахувати» і я би уникав використання цього слова в іншому значенні. Хоча грубою помилкою друге значення я б теж не назвав. На жаль, у сучасній прозі це слово з'являється у другому значенні занадто часто.

Comment: Оновлена інформація заслуговує на додатковий бонус. Через 24 години сайт дозволить мені зробити це.

Comment: Цікаве досліження! Дякую!

Comment: _«Я обробив три збірки, але відкинув всі сучасні твори (крім **Винниченка** для порівняння)»_ — може «Винничук»?

Comment: ***Чудово!*** Трішки критики: (1) Неочевидні мотиви, якими Ви керувались, обираючи певних авторів / певні твори і невідомий навіть сам перелік творів. Було б добре, якби Ви шукали по якомусь відкритому корпусу на зразок [brown](//github.com/brown-uk/corpus), або хоча б **надали перелік творів**, що ви використовували. Інакше Ваше дослідження ніхто не зможе відтворити (а раптом Ви десь помилилися?). 2. Сковорода писав [доволі специфічною мовою](http://litopys.org.ua/skovoroda/skov1.htm). Багато хто помиляється, приймаючи **сучасні переклади** за оригінальні твори. Чи Ви не помилились також?

Comment: @Jack Так, дійсно, має бути «Винничук». Дякую!

Comment: @Sasha (1) На жаль, у мене було обмаль часу і я хотів зробити все швидко. Тому просто вибрав всі твори у форматах, що легко опрацьовувати. Саме для того, щоб уможливити відтворення я додав першу збірку, яку можна завантажити зі сторінки [PocketBook](http://www.pocketbook-int.com/ua/uk/support/pocketbook-basic-touch). Взагалі мені спало на думку, що треба скласти і випустити збірку творів для подібних досліджень. Якщо є бажання, може спробуємо разом? (2) Я згоден щодо Сковороди. Я не можу з певністю сказати, чи це його оригінальні твори чи ні.

Answer (score 9):

> <sup>[Газета „Хрещатик“](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B0-%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3#.D0.A5.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.89.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BA) ¬ [Уроки української мови](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/155.htm) [(Борис Рогоза)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)</sup>
>   **Займатися — працювати, робити, навчатися**
>
> Дієслово *займатися* стало просто-таки універсальним. Поширюючи без потреби значеннєвий масштаб цього слова, витискуємо ним з ужитку здавна відомі українські вислови. Наприклад, кажемо: *займатися торгівлею* замість *торгувати*, *займатися ремонтом* замість *ремонтувати, лагодити, займатися своєю справою* замість *робити свою справу (діло)*. Це надає мовленню одноманітності й звужує, збіднює наші лексично-виражальні можливості.
>
> Основне значення дієслова *займатися* — *„загорятися, спалахувати“*. [„І в той час скирти і клуня *зайнялися*“](http://litopys.org.ua/shevchenko/shev203.htm) (Тарас Шевченко). Від нього походять *займистий, займистість, легкозаймистий, незаймистий*. Щодо омонімічного *займатися*, яке набуло нового змісту шляхом метафоризації, то воно використовується набагато рідше і слушне тоді, коли мовиться про *захоплення, зацікавлення*: *займатися співом, займатися спортом*. У інших випадках годиться застосовувати слова: *провадити, працювати, навчатися, робити, братися* і под. Не *займатися реставрацією*, а *провадити її*; не *займатися якоюсь темою*, а *працювати над нею*; не *займатися на курсах*, а *навчатися*; не *займатися самим собою*, а *братися за самого себе*.

---

> <sup>[Книга](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%BA_%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE) [„Як ми говоримо“](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/zajmatysya-pracyuvaty-zhyty-z-chohos-trudytysya-chymos) [(Борис Антоненко-Давидович)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)</sup>
>   **Займатися, працювати, жити з чогось, трудитися чимось, робити щось, заходжуватися коло чогось, узятися за щось**
>
> Відповідно до російського дієслова *заниматься* в нас часто кажуть *займатися*, вельми поширюючи значеннєвий масштаб цього слова й витискаючи ним здавна відомі українські вислови, наприклад: *«займатись пасічництвом»*, замість *пасічникувати*; *«займатися вчителюванням»*, замість *учителювати*; *«займатися столяруванням»*, замість *столярувати*.
>
> Основне значення дієслова *займатися* — «починати горіти, спалахувати»: [«І в той час скирти і клуня *зайнялися*»](http://litopys.org.ua/shevchenko/shev203.htm) (Тарас Шевченко). Значення цього дієслова часом поширювали, вживаючи стосовно навчання:
>
> «Революцією я тоді не *займався*, проте зовсім темним не був, читав різні книжки…» [(Юрій Яновський)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%AE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87).
>
> Є багато висловів, які можуть заміняти дієслово *займатися*: *жити з чогось* або *чимось* («І дід, і батько його *жили з кравецтва*». — *З* живих уст; [«Він *живе хліборобством*».](http://services.ulif.org.ua/grinch/Entry/index?wordid=48903) — Борис Грінченко), *[трудитися](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/110.htm) чимось* («У нас тут усі *трудяться гончарством*». — Із живих уст), *робити щось* ([«Наталці треба не письменного, а хазяїна доброго, щоб умів *хліб робити*».](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=o4-6CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT13&lpg=PT13&dq=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%86%D1%96%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE,%20%D0%B0%20%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE,%20%D1%89%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B2%20%D1%85%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B1%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=qIXtN8Hh7N&sig=CgqRBrNprXb_qUAeFbx8u-99nWw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjehdHJy6TVAhUDOJoKHeFHAo8Q6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%86%D1%96%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%B0%20%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%89%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B2%20%D1%85%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B1%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&f=false) — Іван Котляревський).
>
> Усі ці вислови, взяті з народних джерел, цілком можуть замінити оті штучні конструкції з дієсловом *займатися* на зразок *«займатися кравецтвом»*, *«займатися хліборобством»*.
>
> Замість казати: «Брат зараз *займається* й не може піти в кіно», — слід: «брат зараз *працює*», замість: «Треба *займатись* самим собою», — правильніше: «треба *заходитись* коло самого себе» або: «треба *взятися* за самого себе».

---

> <sup>[Словарь](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) [української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/grinch/Entry/index?wordid=12692) [(Борис Грінченко)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)</sup>
>   **Займа́тися** и **заніма́тися**, -ма́юся, -єшся, *сов. в.* **зайня́тися** и **заня́тися**, -йму́ся, -мешся, *гл.* Загораться, загорѣться, воспламеняться, воспламениться. *Дмеш, дмеш, — ніяк не займається. Дров нарубав гнилих, то вони підсохнуть трохи та й займуться.* Рудч. Ск. І. 124. *Еге, гаси тепер, як занялось!* Хата, 138.
>
> **на зорю́, на світ займа́тися.** Свѣтать. *Почина на світ займатись.* МВ. ІІ. 61. *Іще й на зорю не займається* — імла. МВ. І. 13.
>
> 2) Краснѣть, покраснѣть отъ гнѣва, вспыхивать, вспыхнуть. *А він як відкаже добре панові, то той так і займеться.* Черк. у. *Очі горіли, вся зайнялась і уші почервоніли.* Г. Барв. 218.
>
> 3) **дух заня́вся.** Дыханіе захватило. *Руки й ноги затрусились, у животі похолонуло, і дух занявсь, а сама ні з місця.* Кв. І. 31.

---

> <sup>[Словники УЛІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) ¬ займатися</sup>
>   *починати горіти*
>
> 1. **Синонімія**
>
> **Загорітися** (почати горіти), **зайнятися**, **запалитися**, **спалахнути**, **спахнути**, **запалати**, **запалахкотіти**, **блиснути**, **палахнути** *розм.* (раптово й швидко); **затеплитися** *розм. заст.* (про слабкий вогонь свічки, лампадки). - Недок.: **загорятися [загоратися]**, **займатися**, **запалюватися**, **спалахувати**, **спалахкувати** *розм.* **спахати**, **спахувати**, **блискати**. *Полум'я спахнуло, і швидко зайнялася брама, зайнялася й дерев'яна башта над брамою* [(Іван Нечуй-Левицький)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B9-%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87);
>
> 2. **Антонімія**
>
> **Запалюватися ~ гаснути, спалахувати ~ затухати, займатися ~ затухати**
>
> 1 — Загорятися
>   2 — Гаснути
>
> 1. 1. Починати горіти, світити, запалюватися, спалахувати.
>    2. Переставати горіти, світити, затухати, тухнути.
> 2. 1. *У перен. знач.: (про події, почуття)* починатися, збуджуватися.
>    2. Втрачати силу вияву, зменшуватися.

Comment: Дякую [Kyrylo Yatsenko](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2525/#comment4040_2525) й [rbrisk](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2525/#2533) за знайдені матеріали.

Comment: Дуже схильна до прийняття цієї віповіді. Але ж... що робити із цитатами, до прикладу, Ольги Кобилянської, Михайла Коцюбинського, Степа Васильченка, що їх наводить СУМ на підтвердження значення 1 дієслова *займатися*?

Comment: Пан rbrisk зробив чудовий аналіз й, схоже, там є відповідь на „що робити“.

Answer (score -2):

Я б сказав, і «займатися справою» (про людину), і «займатися полум'ям» (про займистий предмет) — у сучасній українській мові прийнятні. У першому випадку, має сенс замінювати цей зворот на самостійне дієслово (напр., замість «займатися пасічництвом» — «пасічникувати»), або використовувати обидві форми паралельно як синіми, тим самим збагачуючи свою мову. Проте, така можливість є не завжди («займися справою» не замінюється на «справуй», як і «займися чимось» на «чимсюй»), тож, при всьому авторитеті пана Пономарева, залишити за «займатися» виключно значення «загорятися» неможливо.

Comment: Я згоден, що Пономарів у даному випадку занадто пуристичний, а слово «займатися» в сучасній українській мові можна використовавати і в значенні «займатися справою», а не лише «займатися полум'ям». Але, формально кажучи, з того, що «займатися справою» не можна висловити одним словом («справувати»), не випливає, що використання «займатися» в цьому випадку є правильним, а не русизмом/росіянізмом — можливо, оте варто «справувати» варто висловлювати двома словами, але іншими (наприклад, «робити справу»). (Це **не** моя точка зору, я лише кажу, що лише з відсутності «справувати» нічого не випливає.)

Comment: Слово [_справуй_](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) цїлком існує, хоча наразї _займись справою_ часто використовують в сенсї _працюй_ чи щось на штиб цього. Щодо _займися чимось_ — існує [_візьмися_](http://sum.in.ua/s/uzjatysja)

Comment: Якщо слово чи зворот є русизмом, це ще не означає, що воно є неправильним в українській мові. Об'єктивно, ми перебуваємо в настільки тісному контакті з російською, що нам здебільшого важко позбутися однієї російської кальки, не винайшовши іншу таку ж кальку, тому має сенс говорити лише про ненормативні русизми. Але, в даному випадку, я бачу лише *бажання* зробити таку конструкцію ненормативною.

Comment: Щодо «справуй» і под. Так, в архаїчному пласті мови вони справді можуть бути — проте, сучасним українцям (навіть тим, що з дитинства українською балакають) вони здебільшого невідомі — ми достеменно не знаємо, що вони означали, в яких випадках вживались, а в яких ні, й інтуїтивно розуміємо їх вміру розуміння знайомих коренів. «Займися чимось» ≠ «візьмися за щось»: перше більше стосується заняття, що почнеться й триватиме якийсь час, друге — докладення зусиль, щоб початичи діяльність, або щоб зробити справу як слід, інтенсивно. Тобто, значення близькі, але не тотожні.

Comment: Я розглянув два випадка: коли конче потребують, аби щось робив чи навіть зробив: _візмися_, як на мене, цїлком підходить тут. Також є мʼякіша форма — _бери_ • _бери справу_. В инших чи в більшостї випадках замінюється такими допоміжними дїєсловами: _почни_, _зроби_, _роби_, бува навіть [_май_](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=мати) чи вся конструкцїя замінюється питомими иншими дїєсловами. До речі, [є](http://sum.in.ua/s/chymchykuvaty) слово [_чимчикуй_](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=чимчикувати) (щоправда, з иншим значенням).

Comment: Ну а як щодо конкретного прикладу: вам набридає нудьгуючий товариш, поки ви пишете важливий коментар. Якщо я міг би сказати йому «Займися чимось!», щоб він спробував відволіктися на щось інше, поки я пишу, то яку фразу з тим же змістом скажете йому ви?